# open/close sidenav bar same button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button that I'm hoping will open and close a side nav.  My button code is:

```
<button class="myBtn" id="myBtn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i></button>
```

I'm trying to use addEventListener and think i may be missing an if statement in this, but can't be sure:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", open);
    function open() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", close);
    function close() {
         document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

any suggestions?  thanks!

Comment: from which side you want your sidenavbar  to come ??

Comment: I guess you can use `if(document.getElementById('mySidenav').offsetWidth == 0)` for `open`

Comment: the sidenavbar is left aligned and will open from the left @AsifuzzamanRedoy

Comment: just add a variable that keep the state of the nav `open or close` (0,1) and on click check it, change it to the opposite value and do an if on state.... and put both functions (open and close) on the event handler of your button (click event)

Comment: Why don't you handle this with CSS? You can have an open class which animates your nav into position then all you need to do is toggle the class when you click the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a toogleFunction

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", toggleNav);

function toggleNav(){
    navSize = document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width;
    if (navSize == 250) {
        return close();
    }
    return open();
}
function open() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}
function close() {
         document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I meant in my comment...

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", open_close);

var menuState = 0 // close
function open_close() {
  if(menuState === 0){
     menuState = 1;
     document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
     //document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
  }
  else {
     menuState = 0;
     document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
     //document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
  console.log(menuState);
}
```

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/diego_carrascal/ubcu072L/1/)

Comment: thanks, this makes sense to me, but I can't seem to get it to close.  it opens great, but remains open.  I thought the typo in the second menuSate was the culprit, but it doesn't work.

Comment: it just do what you aimed to do, so you could better make it visible = true or false...

Answer (score 0):

This is may not a best solution but I try to show a quick solution. That is how I did

```js
 document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", open);
    function open() {
         document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
         document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.height = "500px";
         document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.backgroundColor = "#ddff11";
         // document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
         document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
 }
 document.getElementById("myBtnTwo").addEventListener("click", close);
     function close() {
          document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
         document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
         document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <style>
  
 </style>
</head>
<body>  

<div id="main">
 <div id="mySidenav">
  
 </div>
</div>

<button class="myBtn" id="myBtn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign">Button Open</i></button> 
<button class="myBtn" id="myBtnTwo"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign">Button Close</i></button> 



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

hello This might help you see the below **fiddle** 
  ****ignore the code****

```
 <script>
 var o =document.getElementById("one");
 var to =document.getElementById("two");
 to.style.display = 'none';
 function openNav() {
 document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "150px";
 document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "150px";
 o.style.display = 'none';
 to.style.display = '';
 }
function closeNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
o.style.display = '';
to.style.display = 'none'; 
}
</script>
```

[sidebar fiddle one button](https://jsfiddle.net/Asifuzzaman/fs96h8m4/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to forget about the `EventListener`, here is my contribution:

For you side navigation menu, use:

```
<nav id='rightMenu' style='display:none;'>
  <a href='#' onclick='toggleRightMenu()'>Link 1</a>
  <a href='#' onclick='toggleRightMenu()'>Link 1</a>
  <a href='#' onclick='toggleRightMenu()'>Link 1</a>
</nav>
```

For the button to open (show) and close (hide) the navigation menu, use:

```
<button onclick='toggleRightMenu()'></button>
```

And for the `toogleRightMenu()` code, use:

```
<script>
  function toggleRightMenu() {
    navMenuStatus = document.getElementById('rightMenu').style.display;
    if ( navMenuStatus == 'none' ) {
      document.getElementById('rightMenu').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('rightMenu').style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and most simplific solution would be to toggle the `onclick="function()"` on your button. This is not using `addEventListener` though.

**Add these two lines to your two open and close functions:**

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = close;

document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = open;
```

**Your complete code would then look like this.**

```
function open() {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = close;
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function close() {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = open;
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```